# How can use count/{$sum: 1} in other custom field with $group in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new in mongoDB and i an stuck in one scenario, i want to use count {$sum: 1} in other custom field i try like:

```
$group: {
    _id: "$userId",
    count: { $sum: 1 },
    userId: { $push: "$doerId" },
    message: {"$first": { $concat: [ "$count", " user(s) are available" ] } }
}
```

output:

```
{
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5dceaa9500532a0c4881502e",
            "count": 1,
            "userId": [
                "5dcea3d529a655553ac3c158"
            ],
            "message": null
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dcfd8ce6bf8870d93b0828e",
            "count": 5,
            "userId": [
                "5dd0517a6bf8870d93b082d8",
                "5dceaed500532a0c48815030",
                "5dd4ce9617c65911ea0d6325",
                "5dd51f7417c65911ea0d63ff",
                "5dcea3d529a655553ac3c158"
            ],
            "message": null
        }
    ] }
```

> i need message like: "5 user(s) are "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!!! i tried with different things and got the solution with $project.

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$userId",
        userId: { $first: "$doerId"},
        count: { $sum: 1 },,
    },
}, { 
    $project : {
        _id : 0 ,
        userId: 1,
        count: 1,
        message: { $concat: [ { $convert: { input: "$count", to: "string"} }, " user(s) are available" ] },
    }
}
```

Here i also used $convert because $count us an integer value and $concat only support string value so we convert $count to string and get a message.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite tricky output that you are expecting. Your best bet is to move '**message**' out of '**$group**' and use '**$addFields**'. If you use **Mongo 4.0+**, your Mongo query would be simiilar to as follows:

```
$group: {
_id: "$userId",
count: { $sum: 1 },
userId: { $push: "$doerId" },
},
$addFields:{
message: {$concat: [{$toString:"$count"}, " user(s) are available"]}
}
```

Comment: Can you try the query again? I have added missed brackets.